# Linear approximation using the generalised formula

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

I have been reviewing my analysis course and there is something that seems odd to me.
My professor has wrote that the linear approximation for a function of two variables is :

$ x  = x_{0} + h$ 
$ y  = y_{0} + k$ 
$ h  = x - x_{0}$ 
$ k  = y - y_{0}$ 
$$ f(x_{0}+h,y_{0}+k) = f(x_{0},y_{0}) + \nabla{f}(x_{0},y_{0})*\begin{pmatrix}
h  \\
k  \\
\end{pmatrix} +\text{negligible}.$$

Then, he has explained that in dimension $n$, the formula is generalised as follows :

$$ f(x^{0}+H) = f(x^{0}) + \nabla{f}(x^{0})*H + \frac{1}{2}*H^{T}*\nabla{^2f}(x^0)*H + \text{negligible}.$$

With $x^0$ being :
$\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}^{0}  \\
...  \\
x_{n}^{0}  \\
\end{pmatrix}$
and $ H = \begin{pmatrix}
h_{1}  \\
...  \\
h_{n}  \\
\end{pmatrix} $

I am a bit confused because he gave us an example for a function $(x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2x^2y+4$ to compute :
$$f(1+0.0001,2+0.0006)$$
and he has used the generalised expression instead of the first one.

**Will the result be different ? Because the expressions seem different...**

Comment: The two are different. The first one is called the first order approximation and the second one is the second order approximation.

Comment: Based on your comment and some extra reviewing, I have posted an answer. Would you mind having a look to see if I got it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing my course again and looking at some stuff over the internet I come to the following conclusions :
An approximation can be computed using the n-order approximation and in my coures, we have covered the first and second order approximation.

If you are dealing with a **one-variable function** : 
**1st order approximation** would be $ f(x_{0}+h) = f(x_{0})+f'(x_{0})*h + 0(h^2) $ 
with h the small floating number you want to add to a random integer

**2nd order approximation** would be $ f(x_{0}+h) = f(x_{0})+f'(x_{0})*h + \frac{1}{2}*f''(x_{0})*h^2 $

If you are dealing with a **two-variables function** : 
**1st order approximation** would be :
$ f(x_{0}+h,y_{0}+k) = f(x_{0},y_{0}) + \nabla{f}(x_{0},y_{0})*
\begin{pmatrix}
h  \\
k  \\
\end{pmatrix} +\text{negligible}. $

if you are dealing with a **n-variables function** :

[image]